SHAREPOINT CSOM Workflow 2010 Cancel/Restart Item workflow Powershell
I am trying to write some CSOM Powershell to cancel/restart On-Premise Sharepoint 2013.  The workflows are Workflows 2010.  Workflows 2013 is not allowed.  The background is I don't have access to the server, so using pure CSOM is my only option.
The code is failing right at this section. $WorkflowInstanceService = $WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService() $WorkflowAssociations = $WorkflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($List.Id) $Ctx.Load($WorkflowAssociations) $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
Here is the error Error: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetWorkflowSubscriptionService new Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager() ""
Any ideas what I am doing wrong?
###############################################HERE IS THE FULL CODE################
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll" 
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.dll"

#Set Parameters 
$SiteURL="https://xxxxxxxx.net/sites/xxx/xxxx/" 
$ListName ="xxxxx" 
$WorkflowName ="xxxx"

Try
{ 
#Setup the context 
$Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)

#Get the Web, List and List Items Object
$Web = $Ctx.Web
$Ctx.Load($Web)
$List = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle($ListName)
$ListItems = $List.GetItems([Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery]::CreateAllItemsQuery())
$Ctx.Load($List)
$Ctx.Load($ListItems)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Initialize Workflow Manager and other related objects
$WorkflowServicesManager = New-Object    Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager($Ctx, $Web)
$WorkflowSubscriptionService = $workflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowSubscriptionService()
$Ctx.Load($WorkflowSubscriptionService )
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
$WorkflowInstanceService = $WorkflowServicesManager.GetWorkflowInstanceService()
$WorkflowAssociations = $WorkflowSubscriptionService.EnumerateSubscriptionsByList($List.Id)
$Ctx.Load($WorkflowAssociations)
$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()

#Get the Target workflow to Run
$WorkflowAssociation = $WorkflowAssociations | Where {$_.Name -eq $WorkflowName}

#Start Workflow on each List Item
ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems)
{
    #sharepoint online powershell start workflow       
    $Dict = New-Object 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[System.String,System.Object]'
    $Action = $WorkflowInstanceService.StartWorkflowOnListItem($WorkflowAssociation, $ListItem.Id, $Dict)
}

$Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
} Catch { Write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message }
I have tried all kinds of samples from all over the internet.  They all end with the same error. Error: Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Cannot invoke method or retrieve property from null object. Object returned by the following call stack is null. "GetWorkflowSubscriptionService new Microsoft.SharePoint.WorkflowServices.WorkflowServicesManager()

